# Why is the following way to assign a value to a JSON array not working?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code:

```
compareList[productName] = productID + ',' + productHref;
console.log(productName + ' ' + productID + ' ' + productHref + ' ' + compareList.length);
```

Which logs into this (I have removed the link):

Acer Iconia B1-790 [NT.LDFEE.002] 112576 **link removed for confidentiality** 0

As you can see, all three variables are valid strings, but the json object still fails to assign (compareList.length logs as 0). I've been thinking and thinking but I simply can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the expected result? what is the actual result? we can't guess all these with the little information you posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve the more you wait, the less chances you'll get for an answer.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) nor is there a "JSON array"

Comment: What is there to guess? The expected result is that compareList.length should increase, as in the first line I assign a key-value pair to it. However, obviously that does not work as the second line outputs its length as 0.

Comment: An object has no length. If `compareList` is an array, than anything other than a numeric "key" (a.k.a. index) will not influence the `length` of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this version of adding and checking array length can be useful to you?

```js
var compareList=[]

var productName = {productID:'saban',productHref:'http://saulic.com'};
compareList.push(productName);

console.log(compareList.length);
```